# Create an NxM matrix A to an NxMxL matrix B where B[i,j,:] = kronecker_delta(A[i,j])?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Is there a way to convert a NxM matrix A where

- all values of A are positive integers

to an NxMxL matrix B where

- L = 1 + max(A)
- B[i,j,k] = {1 if k==A[i,j] and 0 otherwise}

using loops I have done the following:

```
B = np.zeros((A.shape[0],A.shape[1],1+np.amax(A)))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        B[i,j,A[i,j]] = 1
```

the solution ideally avoids any use of for loops and uses only slicing or indexing or numpy functions

Comment: It would help if you had an small example `A` matrix and showed the expected `B` matrix

Comment: Also you might consider using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to pre-compile this snippet

Comment: Also the numba suggestion is very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample `A`:

```
In [231]: A = np.array([1,0,3,2,2,4]).reshape(2,3)
In [232]: A
Out[232]: 
array([[1, 0, 3],
       [2, 2, 4]])
```

Your code and `B`:

```
In [233]: B = np.zeros((A.shape[0],A.shape[1],1+np.amax(A)))
     ...: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
     ...:     for j in range(A.shape[1]):
     ...:         B[i,j,A[i,j]] = 1
     ...:             
In [234]: B
Out[234]: 
array([[[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]]])
```

Defining arrays to index `B` in way that broadcasts with `A`:

```
In [235]: I,J=np.ix_(np.arange(2),np.arange(3))

In [236]: B[I,J,A]
Out[236]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Use that indexing to change all the 1s of `B` to 20:

```
In [237]: B[I,J,A]=20

In [238]: B
Out[238]: 
array([[[ 0., 20.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [20.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., 20.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0., 20.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0., 20.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 20.]]])
```

the indexes (2,1) and (1,3) pair with (2,3):

```
In [239]: I,J
Out[239]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2]]))
```

There's also newer pair of functions that do that same thing.  I'm more familiar with the earlier method

```
In [241]: np.take_along_axis(B,A[:,:,None],2)
Out[241]: 
array([[[20.],
        [20.],
        [20.]],

       [[20.],
        [20.],
        [20.]]])
    
In [243]: np.put_along_axis(B,A[:,:,None],1,axis=2)

In [244]: B
Out[244]: 
array([[[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Very helpful! I will take a look at np.put_along_axis